# ffmpeg encode image sequence

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg

I have been using ffmpeg to convert a sequence of jpegs to a video using the following syntax:

`ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -i image_%05d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k video.mpg`

It doesn't work:

```
C:\Documents and Settings\Atelier\Mes documents\dev\projets\emptycanvas\testresu
lt\objets\starbuck.tests.TestAnimationSphereInterieur>"c:\Documents and Settings
\Atelier\Mes documents\Téléchargements\ffmpeg-20120608-git-718607b-win32-static\
bin\ffmpeg.exe" -f image2 -i image_%05d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k video.mpg
ffmpeg version N-41416-g718607b Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  8 2012 12:46:19 with gcc 4.6.3
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-ru
ntime-cpudetect --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-frei0r --enable-libass
 --enable-libcelt --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable
-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libnut --enable-libope
njpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libth
eora --enable-libutvideo --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-
libvorbis --enable-libvpx --ena  libavutil      51. 56.100 / 51. 56.100
  libavcodec     54. 25.100 / 54. 25.100
  libavformat    54.  6.101 / 54.  6.101
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 78.101 /  2. 78.101
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
image_%05d.png: No such file or directory
```

On Windows XP...

Comment: Is your first image named `image_00001.png`?

Comment: This error is probably because your image sequence numbering does not start at 00001. Use `-start_number 100` to specify the index of the first frame.

Answer (score 2):

> been using ffmpeg to convert a sequence of **jpegs**
>   ...
>   -i image_%05d.**png**
>   ...
>   image_%05d.**png**: No such file or directory

You might have better luck with `-i image_%05.jpg`.  That will input images named `image_00001.jpg`, `image_00002.jpg`, `image_00003.jpg`, etc.

Comment: I've find better programs like avidemux (File->Open and select the first image in sequence).

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that the window shell expands the %05d. You can prevent that by doubling the %
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -i image_%%05d.png -vcodec mpeg4 -b 800k video.mpg